# Как правильно поступить при проектировании класса?

Tags: c#, проектирование

Хочу написать класс с различными сортировками.
Первоначальная версия была такая:

```
public static T[] BubbleSort(this T[] array, string sortOrder = "ASC")
{
    if (array.Equals(null))
        return null;

    switch (sortOrder.ToLower())
    {
        case "asc":
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 1; j < array.Length - i; j++)
                {
                    if (array[j - 1].CompareTo(array[j]) > 0)
                        Swap(ref array[j - 1], ref array[j]);
                }
            }
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

Мне показалось, что использовать таким образом строку (2 параметр) не красиво и поэтому я решил применить enum:

```
public enum SortOrder
{
    ASC,
    DESC
};
```

И теперь, собственно, сам вопрос: "Куда лучше написать enum?"

- В отдельный файл? Но тогда конечному пользователю придётся таскать с собой два файла (да, я хочу загрузить код на свой github репозиторий).
- Внутри класса? Но тогда, придётся писать огромную строчку из кода:

```
Sorting<int>.SortOrder.ASC
```

вместо

```
SortOrder.ASC
```

- В том же файле, где находится класс, но снаружи? Вроде бы да, но.. Красиво ли это смотрится? Помогите мне решить, как лучше поступить? :)

Исполняемый файл (если enum лежит в отдельном файле или в том же файле, где и класс, но вне класса):

```
int[] array = { 2, 1 };
Sorting<Int32> sortingInt32 = new Sorting<Int32>();
sortingInt32.BubbleSort(array, SortOrder.ASC);
```

Исполняемый файл (enum лежит внутри класса):

```
int[] array = { 2, 1 };
Sorting<Int32> sortingInt32 = new Sorting<Int32>();
sortingInt32.BubbleSort(array, Sorting<int>.SortOrder.ASC); // Вообще не красиво, согласны?
```

Так выглядит мой класс:

```
namespace Sorting
{
    public class Sorting<T>
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо! :)
P.S. Если будут предложения не с enum, с большим интересом рассмотрю.

Comment: В том же неймспейсе, где находится класс, но снаружи.

Comment: Это как-то регламентируется или просто негласное правило хорошего кода? :D

Comment: Ну вам уже это и так почти очевидно. Публичные вложенные типы даже Microsoft не рекомендует использовать.

Comment: Я одного не могу понять `this T[] array` выглядит как расширение, а потом вы показываете вполне обычный класс `public class Sorting<T>`, где и что я упустил? Чем вам метод расширения не зашел?

Comment: Cлучайно добавил более старый код. 
А метод расширения почему-то не хочет работать с чем-то шаблонным что-ли..
Я не очень помню ошибку, но пришел к выводу (видимо ошибочному), что так работать не может, когда наследуем от IComparable<T>.

Comment: Легко же `public static void BubbleSort<T>(this T[] array, SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.ASC) where T : IComparable<T> { ... }` вам не нужно ничего возвращать из метода, если вы сам массив изменяете, а не новый создаете. Если конечно это не Fluent Interface.

Comment: Когда я добавляю ключевое слово this и static к методы BubbleSort, выходит следующая ошибка:
CS1106: Метод расширения должен быть определен в неуниверсальном статическом классе.
Делаю класс static -> ошибка не уходит, почему?)

Comment: ну так поместите метода внутрь чего-то типа `public static class ArrayExtensions { тут метод }`, уберите обобщение у класса, оно у метода уже есть.

Comment: Ого! У меня получилось даже без "public static ArrayExtensions { тут метод } ", убрав просто <T> у класса..
Изначально я так и хотел сделать, это так круто!

Comment: Название класса не имеет значения для методов расширения. Главное чтобы он public static был.

Comment: *"Но тогда конечному пользователю придётся таскать с собой два файла"* - ну нет, **конечный** пользователь никогда в ваш код смотреть не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод расширения вполне резонно смотрится, перечисление можно рядом положить

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static void BubbleSort<T>(this T[] array, SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.ASC)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public enum SortOrder
{
    Asc,
    Desc
}
```

Вызывать как-то так

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 3, 2 };
array.BubbleSort(SortOrder.Desc);
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы посоветовать, как элегантно заменить конструкцию switch-case в методе.
Она используется для определения sortOrder.
Если asc, то по возрастанию, если desc - по убыванию, default => goto asc.
Может существует более элегантный способ, ведь.. Код в case`ах один и тот же, за исключением знаков > и <.
Можно, конечно, обойтись и без этого и написать if внутри циклов, но производительность сильно упадет, ведь проверка будет осуществляться постоянно.
Как лучше сделать?)

Comment: Также есть мысль написать отдельные приватные функции: BubbleSortAsc и BubbleSortDesc.
Выызвать их, если sortOrder.Asc и *.Desc соответственно.
Почему-то идеи в моей голове на индийском языке :D
Тогда уже, наверное, проще просто сделать вместо 3 функций 2 и пользователь сам будет явно выбирать, какую ему использовать.
Я отталкиваюсь от удобства и чистоты кода. :)

Comment: @Danila если у вас появился новый вопрос, его стоит задать отдельно. Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, отметил ваш ответ полезным.

Написал новый вопрос: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1379883/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0/1379909?noredirect=1#comment2453177_1379909]
Если вам не сложно, помогите с выбором :)